Why does Firefox refuse to load sites if there is an entry in the ‘/etc/hosts’ file in macOS 14.4.1 (Sonoma)?
If I make an entry in /etc/hosts for a site, Firefox  (v125.0.3) refuses to load the site. I'm running macOS 14.4.1 (Sonoma).
The entry in the /etc/hosts file is:
93.184.215.14 example.com www.example.com

I've read the answers provided in this Stack Overflow post.
At first, Firefox was completely ignoring my hosts file. Now that I've turned off "DNS over HTTPS" I am getting the "Unable to connect" page.
The network tab reveals:

NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And under timings:

Request Timing
Blocked: 39 ms

If I remove the /etc/hosts entry the page loads normally.  Also, both Chrome and Safari are working fine and respecting my hosts entry.
I've also looked at about:networking#dns which does seem to show the correct IP address. It's almost as if Firefox is blocking an attempt to load any endpoint where DNS is overridden.

Are there any IPv6 addresses shown, if you query your local directory services cache via dscacheutil -q host -a name example.com?

Is "network.trr.exclude-etc-hosts" set to "true" in your firefox configuration?

@M.Behrens - yes. I changed it and this has solved the issue. Apparently, it doesn't matter what the setting is - just changing it causes the file to be read.  Restarting firefox didn't even do this.

Out of curiosity, did you try splitting that one line into two separate lines - so 93.184.215.14 example.com and 93.184.215.14 www.example.com?

@AJM - yes I did, there were comments about this already but they were removed. This issue has been solved - see accepted answer.  Firefox doesn't read changes to the hosts file except when certain events happen - restarting Firefox not being one of them. Which I might add - is stupid.

Take a look a your Firefox configuration (about:config) and search for network.trr.exclude-etc-hosts and make sure it is set to true.

If true we parse the /etc/hosts file and exclude any host names from TRR (Trusted Recursive Resolver). Reading the file is only done once, when TRR is first enabled - this could be soon after startup or when the pref is flipped.


what an oddly named setting.  I assumed 'exclude-etc-hosts' means it excludes /etc/hosts.  It sounds as if it actually READS /etc/hosts but excludes TRR. And now I've discovered that it actually doesn't matter at all - simply flipping the setting causes firefox to re-read the file.  I'm at a loss... I had previously restarted firefox several times so now I'm wondering if that file is read at system startup - not firefox startup.  what's the problem with just reading a file in real time - is that too much overhead?

What is the source of the quote in this answer, please?

Quoted text seems to be from https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2390490af3431aa2b2cdb8f841130a65c0f033c5/modules/libpref/init/StaticPrefList.yaml#L12822-L12828

@muru - the comments in that source are a great resource. I've searched explanations about some of the about:config settings but I've never seen so much good info in one place

@MBehrens - I'd like to request that you update your answer to reflect the fact that it actually doesn't matter what network.trr.exclude-etc-hosts is set to - only that it gets flipped - "Reading the file is only done once, when TRR is first enabled - this could be soon after startup or when the pref is flipped."
